# Is it possible to have a array inside a Dictionary object

Tags: vbscript

I knew that combining to similar data structures wouldn't be logical but curious to know if we can have a array element inside Dictionary object. some thing like:

```
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

d.Add "Name", "John"
d.Add "Age", 31
d.Add "Company", Array("microsoft", "apple")
```

Answer (score 8):

You are one `WScript.Echo` away from solving the question for yourself:

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> d.Add "Company", Array("microsoft", "apple")
>> WScript.Echo Join(d("Company"))
>>
microsoft apple
```

cf [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15096268/603855)

**Update (thanks to @Ansgar):**

The elements delivered by `.Item()` (and `For Each`) are **copies**; and Array assignment copies too (does not take a reference as in other languages). So changing an array element stored in a dictionary means assigning a new array:

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> d.Add "Company", Array("microsoft", "apple")
>> WScript.Echo Join(d("Company"))
>> d("Company") = Array(d("Company")(1), "samsung")
>> WScript.Echo Join(d("Company"))
>>
microsoft apple
apple samsung
```

Sometimes it's more convenient to use a(nother) dictionary, a System.Collections.Arraylist, or a custom object (all objects are references, so an assignment gives access to the original element).

Comment: Beware that you can't directly change elements of the nested array (`d("Company")(1) = "Oracle"` won't work). You have to assign the array to a variable, change it, then assign it back to the dictionary entry.

Comment: And, while you can assign objects as a key, it is not possible to assign an array as a key: `a = array(1,2,3) : d(a) = "array!"` results in a `Invalid procedure call or argument` error. (EDIT: oh, I just see Ekkehard.Horner explaining this in the answer that is under the link in this answer).