# Could Array have values of different Data Type

Tags: vbscript

In general arrays won't have values of different data type but when Items method is used to extract data from dictionary object. It does data of different data type.

Could anyone clarify me on this, is it possible Arrays to have values of different data type?

```
Option Explicit

Dim D, i, Arr

Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

D.CompareMode = VbTextCompare

D.Add "1", 56

D.Add "2", 78

 D.Add "3", "John"

D.Add "4", 100

Arr = D.Items

For i=0 to ubound(Arr) Step+1

Msgbox Arr(i)

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript is very weakly typed. All variables are Variants (of different subtypes: Integers, String, Objects, ...). Collections can hold items of all subtypes; the items can even be of different subtypes.

Even the Keys of a Dictionary don't have to be Strings; they can be Objects just as well. WRT [this question concerning Dictionaries and Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15097463/603855), I have to add: Arrays can be Items, but not Keys of a Dictionary:

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> d.Add "Company", Array("microsoft", "apple")
>> WScript.Echo Join(d("Company"))
>> a = d("Company") <== array assignment in VBScript COPIES!
>> a(1) = "samsung"
>> WScript.Echo Join(a)
>> WScript.Echo Join(d("Company"))
>>
microsoft apple
microsoft samsung
microsoft apple
>> d.Add a, "won't work"
>>
Error Number:       5
Error Description:  Invalid procedure call or argument
```

A subtype to be careful with is Fixed Array (defined with `Dim a(ConstNumber)`). The elements are fairly unrestricted, but I'd be surprised if you could put a Fixed Array into a collection.

**Update (wrt fixed arrays):**

A fixed array and its elements are stored in some special way to improve performance. I don't know anything about the details, but it is a special type of array (which can't grow).

Putting something into a collection means: putting a copy of something (type + value(s)) in. If the something is a simple variable or an array, you loose the connection to the original (thinks again for pointing this out, @Ansgar). If the something is an object, the copy of the reference (object) still gives you access to the data of the original.

The copy of a Fixed Array that goes into the collection (ok, the test uses only a dictionary) looses the special type:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Af(0)   : Af(0) = "fixed"
ReDim Ad(0) : Ad(0) = "dyn"
WScript.Echo 0, Af(0), Ad(0)

Dim dicX : Set dicX = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dicX(0) = Af
dicX(1) = Ad
WScript.Echo 1, dicX(0)(0), dicX(1)(0)
Af(0)    = UCase(Af(0))
Ad(0)    = UCase(Ad(0))
WScript.Echo 2, Af(0), Ad(0)
WScript.Echo 3, dicX(0)(0), dicX(1)(0)
grow dicX(0)
grow dicX(1)
WScript.Echo 4, Join(dicX(0)), Join(dicX(1))
grow Ad
WScript.Echo 5, Join(Ad)
grow Af

Sub grow(a)
  ReDim Preserve a(Ubound(a) + 1)
  a(1) = "array"
  WScript.Echo "**", Join(a)
End Sub
```

output:

```
cscript doa.vbs
0 fixed dyn
1 fixed dyn
2 FIXED DYN
3 fixed dyn
** fixed array
** dyn array
4 fixed dyn
** DYN array
5 DYN array
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\15008949\vbs\doa.vbs(23, 3) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: This array is fixed or temporarily locked
```

The `** fixed array` line proves that the array passed to `grow` is **not** fixed anymore; it's not of the same type as `Af` that can't grow.

Comment: Adding a fixed array to e.g. a dictionary or an arraylist works just fine AFAICS. Why should it not work?