# Add value to array in dictionary

Tags: arrays, dictionary, vbscript

I have a dictionary where the values are all arrays.  I'm trying to add values to the arrays.  [According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095536/is-it-possible-to-have-a-array-inside-a-dictionary-object), you can't directly change the value, so I'm attempting to assign the value to a temporary array, add the item, remove the key then readd it to the dictionary using the new array.  However, I'm running into issues.

```
        if ds.Exists(count.key) then
            'set temp array length to ds.Item length
            ReDim Preserve v(UBound(ds.item(count.key)))    
            'set temp array to ds.item values
            v = ds.item(count.key)
            'set temp array length to ds.Item length + 1
            ReDim Preserve v(UBound(ds.item(count.key)) + 1)
            'add new value to the end of the temp array
            v(UBound(v)) = count.val
            'remove key
            ds.remove(count.key)
            'add key with updated array
            ds.add count.key,v 
        else
            ds.add count.key,array(count.val)
        end if
```

Currently I get a type mismatch error on `v = ds.item(count.key)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem was actually declaring and trying to `ReDim` the array.  I completely removed that line and it works.

```
    if ds.Exists(count.key) then    
        'set temp array to ds.item values
        v = ds.item(count.key)
        'set temp array length to ds.Item length + 1
        ReDim Preserve v(UBound(ds.item(count.key)) + 1)
        'add new value to the end of the temp array
        v(UBound(v)) = count.val
        'remove key
        ds.remove(count.key)
        'add key with updated array
        ds.add count.key,v 
    else
        ds.add count.key,array(count.val)
    end if
```