# Change element of array stored as Vb Scripting.Dictionary Item

Tags: vbscript

I like to use arrays as "Items" associated with the keys in a dictionary.  This enables me to store multiple values associated with a key.  I would like to use the same method to *change* elements in the arrays too.  However the following doesn't work.

```
dim d
set d = createobject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'populate
d.add "A", Array(0,0)

'Change value of element 0.
d.Item("A")(0) = 1

'Result
WScript.Echo d.Item("A")(0) 'Prints zero instead of 1.
```

By saving the array as a temporary variable I can get it to work, but it is more cumbersome.

```
'populate
d.add "A", Array(0,0)

'Change value of element 0.
ar = d.Item("A")
ar(0) = 1
d.Item("A") = ar

'Result
WScript.Echo d.Item("A")(0)
```

I am wondering why this behavior exists, and what's the best way to change a single element in an array that is stored as a dictionary "Item".  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use a disconnected recordset, one that is created in memory. That is a table. You can have as many columns as you want. Here I'm using one as a sort engine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552725/sorting-files-by-numerical-order

Comment: Knew I’d seen this question before, the duplicate [answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15097463/692942) that the array is a copy not a reference so to assign new values you have to pass the entire new array.

Comment: Thank you all so much!  I now why this works the way it does, and I've got some other tools in my belt (disconnected recordset and ArrayList).

Comment: I've used nested dictionary objects and custom to do this before.  Storing an array as an "Item" seemed much simpler... but it was obvious that I wasn't getting a reference to the array.  Just didn't understand why.

Comment: @ACatInLove so is it [Humberto Freitas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732138/humberto-freitas) or [Serenity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4772375/serenity) who is your alter ego then, because you haven't given an answer on that [particular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552725/sorting-files-by-numerical-order)?

Comment: I am many because I will never enter passwords, so everytime IE crashes I become a new user. I guess it the table answer - sorting using a disconnected recordset.